# How access Text of a textbox in class of stimulsoft file

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a function I wrote on stimulsoft report code :

```
public static ChangeTextBoxValue(string s)
{
     return s + " S.T ";
}
```

And in a textbox in designer I wrote an expression :

```
 {ChangeTextBoxValue(Text1.Text)}
```

But at preview it return only `" S.T "` .

I try this too, But it didn't work too:

```
public static ChangeTextBoxValue()
    {
         return Text1.Text + " S.T ";
    }
```

By this expression on textbox:

```
 {ChangeTextBoxValue()}
```

Comment: did you check Text1.Text on run time?

Comment: Yes, It has value. Text1 contains sum a filed of my group

Comment: please show your full code

Comment: full code of what? I haven't any extra code in my report code but this function

Comment: well,i can't understand where is this code?is it a c# code?

Comment: Yes. But it's embedded code of stimulsoft, not visual studio project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to use Text1.Text expression in other component. Because after rendering there are many Text1 componnents on report pages and usually they have different values. Which one should be used?

You should use the same expression as you use in Text1 component. This expression will be calculated for this component.